# How can a container setup using Dockerfile communicate with a localhost:xxxx made available by another container setup using docker-compose?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-network

My **docker-compose** looks like below:

```
version: "3.0"
services:
  elasticsearch:
    container_name: elastic-container
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.13.4
    environment:
      - xpack.security.enabled=false
      - "discovery.type=single-node"
    networks:
      - ek-net
    ports:
      - 9200:9200
networks:
  ek-net:
    driver: bridge
```

It runs elasticsearch on `http://localhost:9200/`.

I have **another container** (created from a simple **Dockerfile**) which executes a ruby script to connect to `http://localhost:9200/`, however I get the following error:

```
/usr/local/lib/ruby/3.1.0/socket.rb:1214:in `__connect_nonblock': Failed to open TCP connection to localhost:9200 (Cannot assign requested address - connect(2) for [::1]:9200) (Faraday::ConnectionFailed)
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/3.1.0/socket.rb:1214:in `connect_nonblock'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/3.1.0/socket.rb:56:in `connect_internal'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/3.1.0/socket.rb:137:in `connect'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/3.1.0/socket.rb:642:in `block in tcp'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/3.1.0/socket.rb:227:in `each'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/3.1.0/socket.rb:227:in `foreach'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/3.1.0/socket.rb:632:in `tcp'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/3.1.0/net/http.rb:998:in `connect'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/3.1.0/net/http.rb:976:in `do_start'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/3.1.0/net/http.rb:965:in `start'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/faraday-net_http-1.0.1/lib/faraday/adapter/net_http.rb:138:in `request_via_get_method'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/faraday-net_http-1.0.1/lib/faraday/adapter/net_http.rb:129:in `request_with_wrapped_block'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/faraday-net_http-1.0.1/lib/faraday/adapter/net_http.rb:122:in `perform_request'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/faraday-net_http-1.0.1/lib/faraday/adapter/net_http.rb:66:in `block in call'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/faraday-1.10.0/lib/faraday/adapter.rb:50:in `connection'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/faraday-net_http-1.0.1/lib/faraday/adapter/net_http.rb:64:in `call'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/faraday-1.10.0/lib/faraday/rack_builder.rb:154:in `build_response'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/faraday-1.10.0/lib/faraday/connection.rb:516:in `run_request'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/elastic-transport-8.0.1/lib/elastic/transport/transport/http/faraday.rb:49:in `block in perform_request'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/elastic-transport-8.0.1/lib/elastic/transport/transport/base.rb:298:in `perform_request'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/elastic-transport-8.0.1/lib/elastic/transport/transport/http/faraday.rb:36:in `perform_request'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/elastic-transport-8.0.1/lib/elastic/transport/client.rb:176:in `perform_request'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/elasticsearch-8.3.0/lib/elasticsearch.rb:161:in `elasticsearch_validation_request'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/elasticsearch-8.3.0/lib/elasticsearch.rb:85:in `verify_elasticsearch'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/elasticsearch-8.3.0/lib/elasticsearch.rb:70:in `method_missing'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/elasticsearch-api-8.3.0/lib/elasticsearch/api/actions/search.rb:99:in `search'
    from test_scripts_1/test_es_connection.rb:14:in `<main>'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/3.1.0/socket.rb:1214:in `__connect_nonblock': Failed to open TCP connection to localhost:9200 (Cannot assign requested address - connect(2) for [::1]:9200) (Errno::EADDRNOTAVAIL)
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/3.1.0/socket.rb:1214:in `connect_nonblock'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/3.1.0/socket.rb:56:in `connect_internal'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/3.1.0/socket.rb:137:in `connect'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/3.1.0/socket.rb:642:in `block in tcp'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/3.1.0/socket.rb:227:in `each'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/3.1.0/socket.rb:227:in `foreach'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/3.1.0/socket.rb:632:in `tcp'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/3.1.0/net/http.rb:998:in `connect'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/3.1.0/net/http.rb:976:in `do_start'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/3.1.0/net/http.rb:965:in `start'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/faraday-net_http-1.0.1/lib/faraday/adapter/net_http.rb:138:in `request_via_get_method'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/faraday-net_http-1.0.1/lib/faraday/adapter/net_http.rb:129:in `request_with_wrapped_block'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/faraday-net_http-1.0.1/lib/faraday/adapter/net_http.rb:122:in `perform_request'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/faraday-net_http-1.0.1/lib/faraday/adapter/net_http.rb:66:in `block in call'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/faraday-1.10.0/lib/faraday/adapter.rb:50:in `connection'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/faraday-net_http-1.0.1/lib/faraday/adapter/net_http.rb:64:in `call'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/faraday-1.10.0/lib/faraday/rack_builder.rb:154:in `build_response'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/faraday-1.10.0/lib/faraday/connection.rb:516:in `run_request'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/elastic-transport-8.0.1/lib/elastic/transport/transport/http/faraday.rb:49:in `block in perform_request'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/elastic-transport-8.0.1/lib/elastic/transport/transport/base.rb:298:in `perform_request'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/elastic-transport-8.0.1/lib/elastic/transport/transport/http/faraday.rb:36:in `perform_request'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/elastic-transport-8.0.1/lib/elastic/transport/client.rb:176:in `perform_request'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/elasticsearch-8.3.0/lib/elasticsearch.rb:161:in `elasticsearch_validation_request'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/elasticsearch-8.3.0/lib/elasticsearch.rb:85:in `verify_elasticsearch'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/elasticsearch-8.3.0/lib/elasticsearch.rb:70:in `method_missing'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/elasticsearch-api-8.3.0/lib/elasticsearch/api/actions/search.rb:99:in `search'
    from test_scripts_1/test_es_connection.rb:14:in `<main>'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/3.1.0/socket.rb:1214:in `__connect_nonblock': Cannot assign requested address - connect(2) for [::1]:9200 (Errno::EADDRNOTAVAIL)
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/3.1.0/socket.rb:1214:in `connect_nonblock'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/3.1.0/socket.rb:56:in `connect_internal'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/3.1.0/socket.rb:137:in `connect'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/3.1.0/socket.rb:642:in `block in tcp'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/3.1.0/socket.rb:227:in `each'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/3.1.0/socket.rb:227:in `foreach'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/3.1.0/socket.rb:632:in `tcp'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/3.1.0/net/http.rb:998:in `connect'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/3.1.0/net/http.rb:976:in `do_start'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/3.1.0/net/http.rb:965:in `start'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/faraday-net_http-1.0.1/lib/faraday/adapter/net_http.rb:138:in `request_via_get_method'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/faraday-net_http-1.0.1/lib/faraday/adapter/net_http.rb:129:in `request_with_wrapped_block'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/faraday-net_http-1.0.1/lib/faraday/adapter/net_http.rb:122:in `perform_request'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/faraday-net_http-1.0.1/lib/faraday/adapter/net_http.rb:66:in `block in call'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/faraday-1.10.0/lib/faraday/adapter.rb:50:in `connection'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/faraday-net_http-1.0.1/lib/faraday/adapter/net_http.rb:64:in `call'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/faraday-1.10.0/lib/faraday/rack_builder.rb:154:in `build_response'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/faraday-1.10.0/lib/faraday/connection.rb:516:in `run_request'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/elastic-transport-8.0.1/lib/elastic/transport/transport/http/faraday.rb:49:in `block in perform_request'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/elastic-transport-8.0.1/lib/elastic/transport/transport/base.rb:298:in `perform_request'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/elastic-transport-8.0.1/lib/elastic/transport/transport/http/faraday.rb:36:in `perform_request'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/elastic-transport-8.0.1/lib/elastic/transport/client.rb:176:in `perform_request'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/elasticsearch-8.3.0/lib/elasticsearch.rb:161:in `elasticsearch_validation_request'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/elasticsearch-8.3.0/lib/elasticsearch.rb:85:in `verify_elasticsearch'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/elasticsearch-8.3.0/lib/elasticsearch.rb:70:in `method_missing'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/elasticsearch-api-8.3.0/lib/elasticsearch/api/actions/search.rb:99:in `search'
    from test_scripts_1/test_es_connection.rb:14:in `<main>'
```

I tried running the 2nd container by doing `docker run -p 9200:9200` and `EXPOSE 9200` however I'm still seeing the same error. I'm guessing this is an issue that needs to be addressed on the docker-compose side. Please help clarify why this happens and what is the best way to fix it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use localhost in the Ruby application like this, it resolves to the address on the *container* and not on the *host*.

To gain access to the host instead, you can use `host.docker.internal` instead of `localhost`, e.g http://host.docker.internal:9200/

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24319662/from-inside-of-a-docker-container-how-do-i-connect-to-the-localhost-of-the-mach) post for a thorough explanation